# Ignore containing folder, but not a folder within

Tags: wordpress, git, module, themes, gitignore

I'm cleaning up my development workflow and I was wondering if it is at all possible for Git to ignore a containing folder, but allow folders within?

Allow me to clarify.

I'm currently working on my website and I'm theming my new Wordpress blog - Obviously I have a local installation of Wordpress and a remote installation. I want to be able to ignore the main folders and only allow the themes folder. The structure is as follows.

- Blog

  - wp-content
  - wp-includes

    - themes
    - modules
  - [...]

I want to ignore absolutely everything except the themes and modules folder - how would I do this in my .gitignore?

Comment: Github != git; Also please don't use signatures in your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
# Ignore everything in the top-most directory
/*

# Except the wp-includes directory
!wp-includes/

# Exclude everything in the wp-includes directory
wp-includes/*

# Except the folders themes and modules
!wp-includes/themes/
!wp-includes/modules/
```

Comment: Thankyou, I kind've mucked up a little bit by naming the directories wrong in my original answer(themes and *plugins* (not modules) are in wp-content not includes, my bad :) ) This works great except for a few things, it seems to be ignoring everything after !wp-includes/ as it's adding the index.php to version control - however this isn't really a problem, thank you very much sir!